# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints despite of a condition

Tags: swift, layout, nslayoutconstraint

First of all, I don't use storyboard, I setup my elements in a `UICollectionView` programmatically.
Depending I have items or not in my `UICollectionView`, I display a `UIView` at 16px or 88px from the top and for this, I use a `switch` condition that doesn't seem to be respected.

I use a classical condition :

```
switch numberOfItems {
    case 0:
        print("nothing here")
        holderButtons.isHidden = true
        BottomView.anchor(top: bottomContainerView.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 16, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    default:
        print("1 or more")
        holderButtons.isHidden = false
        BottomView.anchor(top: bottomContainerView.topAnchor, leading: nil, bottom: nil, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 88, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
}
```

I also tried with a `if...else`.

The condition works fine for the hidden view, but not for my `BottomView`.
Here is the message from the debug area :

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280f385a0 V:|-(16)-[UIView:0x1479337d0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x147933410 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280f13930 V:|-(88)-[UIView:0x1479337d0]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x147933410 )>
```

I don't see what's the problem with it.
Any idea ?

Comment: Have you used "yourView.layoutIfNeeded()" after change constraint value?

Comment: Is `numberOfItems` hard coded or is it dynamic from a server? If your `collectionView` initially has 0 items and later it has more items then you will run into this problem.

Comment: @Fadielse I reloaddata from the main ViewController and it works fine, expect when  I scroll to the top (once the number of items is longer than my view) : My BottomView takes its initial value (top : 16).

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla, my items are stored in CoreData as entities.

Comment: when I go back to my previous view and come again to my CollectionView, no more problems, no more bugs...

Comment: Does your `.anchor(...)` func **delete** existing constraints? If not, you are adding ***additional*** bottom constraints. You need to either modify the existing one (change its `.constant` property), or delete the previously added constraint before adding a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i finally added my condition to a "setupElements" func and it works fine : no more NSLayoutConstraint mistakes in my debug area.
Even if I still have my initial problem when I scroll over my     UICollectionView    : I have a stretchy header and when I expand it until I don't see anymore my cells, it re-inits my condition... it's another problem :)

Comment: Ok, I understand where my problem comes from :  my Stretchy header has a shouldInvalidateLayout func, so it re-inits my view each time I scroll over my UICollectionView